# Histogram in R - x-axis not centered properly

Tags: r, histogram

I have a histogram from a list `d` of values that I make by simply typing

```
hist(d)
```

And this is what I get: [image]

How can I make it such that the x-axis extends all the way left to the origin of this plot (the bottom left corner)? Why does it cut off at -0.4?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Macro's answer is by far the simplest route. However, if you really are unhappy with with the default behavior of `hist` (really, it's the default behavior of `axis` I suppose) you can always suppress the axes and draw them yourself:

```
set.seed(123)
d <- rnorm(1000)
hist(d,axes = FALSE)
axis(1,at = seq(-3,3,1),labels = TRUE,pos = 0)
axis(2,pos = -3)
```

[image]

As for the "why?", the defaults for drawing axes have to be set at something, and so there's a lot of code under there that tries pretty hard to ensure that the axis and tick labels are "pretty" according to the sensibilities of, well, whoever wrote it. In general, I think it does a good job, but of course not everyone agrees.

Answer (score 4):

you can tweak the range of `x` using the `xlim` tag. For example, try

```
hist(d,xlim=c(-10,10))
```

Answer (score 3):

Two suggestions:

```
#See if this is sufficient:
hist(...)
box()

#If not, try custom axes:
hist(..., xlim = c(-.5, .5), axes = F)
box()
axis(1, seq(-.5, .5, length = 6))
axis(2, seq(0, 30, by = 5))
```

Comment: I see @joran beat me to an `axis()` answer.. I still think `box()` is pretty crucial whenever using `hist()`. Definitely see `?axis` though!

Comment: (+1) `box()` is a good suggestion that I didn't think of, yes!